# basic http auth via ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I'm trying to make a http basic auth via ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'secure/index.php',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("user" + ":" + "password") //May need to use "Authorization" instead
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwBnError){
            alert(xhr);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
```

Ok. The problem is that I don't use any .htaccess file to do the HTTP auth.

I have a simple PHP file where this make the authentication:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secret page"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

And my ajax request does not want to work..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you calling `send()` ? If so what's the error or return code

Comment: i'm not sure.. what do u mean exactly?

Comment: sorry, wrong framework in my mind concerning send. But what exactly is not working?

Comment: nothing happens.. no errors returned! the jQuery is not executed!

if I comment the xhr.setRequestHeader line, I have the prompt form to enter my username and password. But what I want is a simple HTML form that sends credentials via ajax!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before; 
try adding this function to your php authentication file

```
function http_auth_get($url,$username,$password){
$cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s',
base64_encode("$username:$password") );
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
            'method'=>'GET',
            'header'=>$cred
        )
);
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$handle = @fopen($url, 'r', false,$ctx);

 if (!$handle) {         
      die($http_response_header[0]);
 }

return stream_get_contents($handle);
}
```

you can use the function as follows:

```
$return = http_auth_get(http://example.com,user,pass);
```

how you use the $return variable depends on what you are trying to access

Comment: How do I use this function next? I don't really know where to put it in my php file..

Comment: put it at the top of you secure/index.php file then call the function using the URL, username and password of the resource you are trying to access. assign the return of the function to a variable ($return or similar) and then you have the contents of the resource you are trying to access in the variable $return

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I make an ajax request on a "index.php" file where I put your function and the final line: echo http_auth_get('basic.php','user','pass'); but my ajax request return the php code of "basic.php" without executing it...

Comment: if i don't do the "echo", the php is probably executed but nothing is returned.. good username/password or not

Comment: In fact my final goal is to make a secure request to a RESTful API (in PHP) via HTTP...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the username and password fields in .ajax?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain/mypage.php",
    username: u,
    password: p,
    error: function () {
    }
}).done(function(html) {
        //Do Stuff
});
```

This works for me almost all of the time.