# BASIC Authenticate via PHP script

Tags: php, apache

I'm new to this particular subject matter. I have spent half a day searching.  I can't take it anymore, so here goes...

I'm working on a site that allows users to upload audio files to the server. I save these files in a folder within the http document. Users can listen to the audio files they uploaded using jPlayer.

I have protected the folder where I saved the songs in with Apache BASIC Authentication in order prevent direct url access by the public at large. But once a user logs in to our web app (using our application's login mechanism), I want that user to have access to the song folder so that he can play his songs (preferrably for the duration of his session).

Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Just an added note, the basic authentication will be made from a php file that is not located within the songs folder.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: What code do you have so far? Also, making web apps (mostly) requires knowledge on various code related elements, and are often not something you learn in "half a day".

Comment: I meant I'm new to http authentication, but not new to PHP or web development. So far, I'm pursuing a lead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626713/basic-http-auth-via-ajax-and-php

Comment: The songs should not be visible on a public url (that's a good approach). But once a user has logged in successfully he/she can access the folder using the server side script. They don't need to open the folder and list its content using some url. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: @TalhaMasood I'm getting your point. And I have taken that into consideration. I'm eventually going to set a unique folder for each user to prevent cross-access between users. I just want to get over this initial hurdle first.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that has worked for me in the past is to use a PHP script to give people access to the files. Let's call this `download.php`. Instead of giving the logged in user direct access to the actual location of the files, they need to access the files through download.php and send the file name as a `$_GET` parameter, like:

download.php?file=some_awesome_song.mp3

This way, you can control things like, number of downloads remaining, whether they need to wait a certain amount of time before downloading it (like a download countdown on certain sites), to prevent them from accessing files from another user, etc.

You could also just forget about HTTP authentication and use .htaccess to completely deny access to the directory that the downloads are located with:

```
deny from all
```

or store the files outside of the web root.

In your PHP do something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Make sure user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    die("You are not logged in");
}

// Make sure user has access to download the file
// Replace with your own methods if applicable
if ($_SESSION['user_has_permission_to_download_file'] === false) {
    die("You don't have permission to access that file");
}

// Make sure we're not trying to open anything outside of that directory
$filename = basename($_GET['file']);
// Replace with the actual location
$path = '/actual/path/to/file/' . $filename;

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    die("The requested file does not exist");
}

if (!is_readable($path)) {
    die("Permission denied while trying to open file");
}

$contents = file_get_contents($path);

// Set content type header based on file
header("Content-type: ".finfo_file($path));

echo $contents;
```

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I think I may have done something similar in the past, too. But this process still does not prevent direct url access once people learn of the actual path. Also, in my case, since I'm streaming the songs, there's a higher likelihood of people finding the actual path (even though the urls are dynamically loaded via ajax). I also need to prevent search engine crawlers from entering this folder and risk them finding potentially illegal audio contents. I also need to prevent cross-access between users. Thanks very much for sharing though.

Comment: Doing it like this would definitely prevent people from using the URL directly. You control this with PHP like I have done above by checking if the user is logged in and if they have permission to download it. So even if they shared the URL with others, they would still be required to be logged in. And the sky's the limit, like making sure the song belongs to that person, or whatever you want. And of course search engines wouldn't be able to access the files either.

Comment: but...if they type something like http://www.yourdomain.com/actual/path/to/file/filename on the browser, the file will be there, won't it?

Comment: No, they would get "You are not logged in" displayed to them. And if they are logged in, then you need to make sure they have permission to download the file. If it belongs to another user, then don't allow them to download it.

Comment: Say your song is located in /music/mysong.mp3...in your download script you would load it like this $path = '/music/mysong.mp3'; correct?  but, if the user type http://yourdomain/music/mysong.mp3, the browser will go directly to your mp3 file. I do not think you can prevent access via PHP, because you're not accessing any script. You're accessing the very file directly.

Comment: The browser is not redirected at all. The PHP script gets the contents of the file and echoes it back to the browser.

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that it can be bypassed once the actual url of where the files are stored is discovered. like this [link](http://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/0/0b/Ryze.attack5.ogg). Which is possible with search engine crawlers and other means we'll never conceive.

Comment: If the files are stored outside the web root, it would be impossible for search engines or anything else to download them through the web server because there would be no "actual URL" in this case.

Comment: That's true. But as I have mentioned in my question, I'm playing audio with jPlayer (a javascript/jquery audio player which runs client-side), which, as far as I can tell, needs direct url to the audio file. So, I can't store the audio files outside of web root.

Comment: I think you're confused about what the point of using the script is in the first place. The URL to download the file will only work if the PHP script gives you access to it based on whether or not you are logged in and have permission to download that particular file.